# Modify a string to show highlight using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on a task to display a string in a textarea/div component where the text will have highlight/background color change according to the array keys.
For eg. If the text and array are:

```
string: "LopemIpsumLopemIpsumLopemIpsumvLopemIpsumLopemIpsumLopemIpsumLopemIpsumLopemIpsumLopemIpsumLopemIpsumLopemIpsumLopemIpsumLopemIpsumLopemIpsumLopemIpsumLopemIpsum"
arr: [{start_highlight:4, end_highlight:8}, {start_highlight:15, end_highlight:30}, {start_highlight:64, end_highlight:68}]
```

then the highlight text from the string should start with 'start_highlight' key and ends with 'end_highlight' key.

I am thinking to use splice but not sure how to use for multiple indexes for same string>

This is the complete source code:

import Parser from 'html-react-parser';
var thisIsMyCopy = string_to_be_parsed_from_array;

render: function() {
return (
{Parser(thisIsMyCopy)}
);
}

Comment: You cannot style text in a `<textarea>` element.

Comment: Perhaps in an element with `contenteditable` ?

Comment: Forgot the textarea, you can think of a div instead

Comment: I think you would need to add `<span class="highlight">` tags to the areas you want to highlight, then adjust the subsequent indices as needed to account for the span tags